# random_image_scale (Data augmentation in the object detection API) does it really work in training?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to find a good combination of data augmentation options for my object detection problem. After checking([object_detection/core/preprocessor.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/b2522f9bb9a559e148502a67ebd9a6592320cb0f/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py#L767)), it seems that the option random_image_scale donesn't function in the training process. The reason is that tf.image.resize_images is used to scale the image, not tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad.

In object_detection/legacy/trainer.py, however, data augmentation is applied first to generate ([input_queue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/b2522f9bb9a559e148502a67ebd9a6592320cb0f/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py#L74)) first. And then input_queue got fed into the pre-defined mata archs for scaling again. So, if tf.image.resize_images is used, although the size of input_queue has been scaled, it will be scaled back to the wanted size when fed into the network, in this way the random_image_scale option doesn't make any sense and instead, waste computation time.

Please let me know if I am wrong.